# How to add method to existing object in Coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Lets say an object is created by some function:

```
myObject = someFunction();
```

So now, `myObject` is an object.

How do I add a new method to this object? The following does not work in Coffeescript:

```
myObject.newMethod: (something) ->
  # do stuff here
```

I am not able to edit the object definition in `someFunction()`, so I have to add the method to the object after the fact. What is the proper syntax here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be `myObject.newMethod = (something) ->`.

You use the colon when declaring a property, and the assignment operator when assigning to a property.  The only time you declare a property, is when the object is being created.  This is also true in JavaScript.

```
var myObject = {foo: 'bar'}; 
myObject.baz = 'quux';
```

---

The best practice is to not modify objects you don't own (someFunction owns that object).  You should instead create a function which takes that kind of object as an argument.